# Sign-in with React using azure/msal-react library

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, msal.js

The azure/msal-react library only has "Popup" or "Redirect" as a signin method.

Is it possible to have the AzureAD login page as the landing page of the web page directly?

Comment: In theory you could take users directly to the login page, but then you'll need to share the AD URL rather than your application's URL which would be a poor user experience. Why can't your application invoke the MSAL redirect as soon as the user lands on your application, even before anything is displayed to the user?

Comment: I agree with @j-petty: if you're linking to your application you'd rather have link be your application's domain as opposed to Microsoft's.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if it possible to embed the Azure AD login page inside an iframe on your page, the answer is no.

Comment: Embedding the login page as an iFrame is possible; it is just not well documented and not enabled out of the box.  

See [How to implement](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/iframe-usage.md), 

[How to enable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow), and

[More info on the embedded experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)